# images loading too slow on product page

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, product-view

i am using the porto theme and images are loading slow even when they are small in size and the server is very fast. it happens in the product page.. what's the cause of this? is that related to the theme?
examples:
https://www.deals4u.co.il/acer-predator-helios-300-gaming-laptop.html
https://www.deals4u.co.il/panasonic-lumix-g7.html

thanks

Comment: I checked product details page, it seems like response time ( TTFB ) is more. Actually image is taking ~290 ms to load, in this 235 ms is the waiting time. You have to try to reduce the TTFB time.

Comment: what can i do about it? how do i reduce the TTFB?

Answer (score 0):

Your image carousel is being loaded with `owl-lazy` parameters. This means that the entire page is being loaded first, then these images are being loaded afterwards. Remove the lazy load parameters from the carousel by removing the class `owl-lazy`.

Comment: Hi Liam, what JS I have to edit and remove the lazy load? in addition i also get an error from the owl carousel on the main page of the website... the error is: owl.carousel.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined. check devlopers mode on https://www.deals4u.co.il

Comment: changed the lazy load to false.. a little better but still not very fast. any more suggestions? thanks!